# Google Sheets Array Formula how to specify which columns to increment and which not to?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a google sheet with & columns: ,User,Purchase,Date,billing date which is being populated from a google form. 
I want the sum of pending expenses for each user.
Billing date is also specific to user.

So far, I populate column F with last billing date with =MAX(FILTER(D:D, A:A = E2)) and then use this for calculating the pending bill using =IFError(SUM(Filter(C2:C,B2:B>F2,A2:A=E2) ),0)

How do I calculate column F and G using Array Formula?
Link to google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g6zHXq_p5yX_6vlco1hTyWWt6eC_wSP-9AI5iLWZNnA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The problem is that aggregate functions like `max` and `sum` cannot be used with `arrayformula`. Neither can `filter`, which is itself an arrayformula. If you can write a script, solve your problem that way. Otherwise, there may be formula workarounds, but usually end up with formulas that are unreadable by normal humans!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the fantastic [Query function](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/).

Something similar to this seems to work: `=QUERY(A2:D,"select A, max(D), sum(C) group by A")` but you will need to nest two queries to get your desired result with the sum.

(note though that in your sheet, you are showing a value for last bill even if a bill hasn't been sent)

Comment: Yeah that's a default value and it still meets the condition so I might just leave it there
I have tried group by A,F as well but that is not producing the write results